# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'version'

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am working on learning how to use pandas but get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_frame.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Users/gregwinter/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "/Users/gregwinter/numpy.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy_compat import *
  File "/Users/gregwinter/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy_compat.py", line 15, in <module>
    _np_version = np.version.short_version
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'version'
```

I have no idea how to fix this. Anything you can tell be on how to fix this would be great.

Comment: Check for a file named `numpy.py` in your current working directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You named a file of your *own* `numpy.py`:

```
/Users/gregwinter/numpy.py
```

Guess which one Python thinks pandas wants to import? :-)  Rename your program, and remove any .pyc or .pyo files that are around.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this same problem after upgrading Jupyter, but did not have a local file named numpy.py. I was able to fix the issue on an Anaconda build by uninstalling/reinstalling pandas using: `conda remove pandas` and then `conda install pandas`

Problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the some error, but the error for my situation is in **mmcv** library. I solve it with

```
pip install --upgrade packaging
```

here is reference [link](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmdetection/issues/5724#issuecomment-1016415834), hope this could help you.