# No module named sklearn.datasets

Tags: python, scikit-learn, importerror

I am running Python 2.7.11 on Mac OS X version 10.6.8 and getting an error.  I am trying to learn how to use sklearn.

I am following http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#loading-an-example-dataset and continually get the following error:

> from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
>
> ImportError: No module named sklearn.datasets

How do I fix this?

Comment: Sklearn is not part of the base Python distribution. Have you installed it? e.g. https://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/

Comment: I do have it installed but I am guessing that it maybe in the wrong place.

Comment: Did you use PIP or easy_install? It should be added to your python path automatically. You haven't given any information on what steps you have done

Comment: Did you name a file the same thing as a module you're trying to use ([again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36137200/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-version))?

Comment: I found the file and thought it might help to place the sklearn in the same folder. This seemed to resolve the orginal problem but now it says "ImportError: No module named numpy"  So I found and placed the numpy file in the same folder again but this did not resolve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to be using some kind of manager to install your modules. pip and easy_install would sort all of this for you, you don't have to move things around. But sklearn will require numpy to work (a separate module), so now you'll need to install that too.

Comment: @roganjosh Thank you so much, I went through pip install.... and this worked.  Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome. You should always try to use pip or easy_install for this kind of thing